# Session Expiration as per Jeff Atwood's Article

Tags: session

Jeff Atwood answered why "So why does the server choose to arbitrarily forget about you in an hour?" in [his blog post about session expiration](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/your-session-has-timed-out.html):

- Performance
- Security

On a closed (exclusive to say 1000 employees of a company) HTTPS system with `X` # of users, is it acceptable to **not** expire sessions, to avoid the inconvenience of re-authentication?

Comment: Are those employees allowed to take connected devices outside of the office?

Comment: Could you please be so kind as to explain the answer for both cases?

Comment: You might be targeting a more appropriate audience if you head to http://security.stackexchange.com or http://programmers.stackexchange.com